# Point M0 cluster to existing M10 cluster that is in the same region and account

Tags: upgrade, mongodb-atlas

I have two clusters in my MongoDB Atlas account, one is M0 and is in Free tier. Other one is, M10 and is in Dedicated Cluster tier. Both these clusters reside in the same region AWS / Frankfurt (eu-central-1). The need is, I have to upgrade my M0 cluster for growing connections and the data storage. But instead of upgrading the cluster, I just want it to be pointed to the M10 cluster that I already have in my account. Is there a way of doing this through MongoDB Atlas? or I will have to upgrade the cluster?

Reason for not upgrading the same cluster (M0) is, when I  tried upgrading it, there appears a warning that says

> Note: Upgrading your cluster to a dedicated tier is irreversible. You
> can make other cluster changes at any time.

and I don't want to have two dedicated clusters as it will add to cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted same question on Mongodb forum and here is an update from the concerned person from Mongodb:

1. Clusters can not be pointed as of now and I will have to upgrade M0 cluster to M2,M5 or M10 as required (I have chosen M10 cluster, as wanted to have dedicated cluster)
2. If I launch a new M10 cluster, will require to migrate the data and for this `mongodump` and `mongorestore` can be used.

Here is the link to the forum:
[Point M0 cluster to existing M10 cluster that is in the same region and account](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/point-m0-cluster-to-existing-m10-cluster-that-is-in-the-same-region-and-account/99095)